# Ionic App was rejected because of blank icon on iPad

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I generated the icons and splash using "ionic cordova resources". The icon is indeed blank when I ran the app on iPad simulator. In my project setting I choose "iPhone" on the devices dropdown under "Devices".

Any idea?

Comment: Your app is universal or only iPhone supported app ?

Comment: Only iPhone supported